# Getting undefined for jQuery position variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$("#capture").click(
    function(event) {
        var photoCoords = $("#doge1").position();
    })
```

I am using the above to get the coordinates of a photo after a user clicks the capture button with the id of #capture.  The image has an id of #doge1.

When I type var photoCoords in console I get a return of undefined.

Comment: An example illustrating rogue_js' answer: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/YvJhE/171/ ;) Take with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a scope issue.  The variable is not accessible outside of the anonymous function.  If your just trying to debug - you could also put the console.log statement in the anonymous function.  Otherwise you need to declare the variable in a scope where its accessible to your log statement.

```
$("#capture").click(
    function(event) {
        var photoCoords = $("#doge1").position();
        console.log(photoCoords);
 })
```

Answer (score 3):

You should write code like follow:

```
var photoCoords;    
$("#capture").click(function(event) {
    photoCoords = $("#doge1").position();
});
```

Comment: still coming in as undefined in console

Answer (score 2):

It's because your variable photoCoords is in the context of an anonymous function inside your click event.  Try declaring it outside of that function and you should be able to access it

Comment: hmm. that literally broke my entire page.  all hidden elements that were being hidden with jquery are visible when i do that.

Comment: tried what @datnguyen suggested and also still getting undefined, if that is how you meant for me to write this

Comment: That was what I meant, essentially.  Did you try logging from within the function?  That will tell you whether it's a jQuery usage problem or a scope problem.

Comment: seems to be a scope problem